# Using jcodec SequenceEncoder

Tags: java, android, mp4, h.264, encoder

I need to create video from images, I have seen jcodec and I think it is what I need:
http://jcodec.org/

How do I add jcodec to my project? I have seen there is a version for android.
Correct me if I am wrong, but I added ***jcodec-0.1.5.jar*** to my project under the libs folder.
Then added ***SequenceEncoder.java*** and ***BitmapUtil.java*** from ***jcodec-android-0.1.7.zip*** to my package but when I add:

```
public void encodeImage(Bitmap bi) throws IOException 
{
    encodeNativeFrame(BitmapUtil.fromBitmap(bi));
}
```

It gives me error on ***package com.example.seqtest*** and asks me to configure build path.

So how I use it, How can I input sequence of images? Can you provide me some example?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is how you do it

1) Download **jcodec-android-0.1.7.zip** from http://jcodec.org/

2) Unzip the downloaded file and you will get **JCodec** folder which is an android project.

3) Import that **JCodec** project in your Eclipse. If you get any error, solve it by right clicking on the project `Properties -> Android -> Select the Build target and press OK`.

4) Now your JCodec library setup is done.

5) Create a new android application project.(your actual project)

6) Right click on the project, `Properties -> Android -> Library -> Add -> Add the JCodec Library -> Apply -> OK`

7) Now your project is linked to JCodec library and you can start coding.

You can download JCodec sample app from this link http://jcodec.org/downloads/jcodec-samples-android-0.1.7.zip

Again you have to carry out step 6 for sample app too.And **no need to add `jcodec-0.1.5.jar` to libs folder.**

Comment: I did that already, there is some conflict problem. When I name the function encodeIm I am not getting the error, but still it does not work. The app is compiling but I get errors when I run it. I need some tutorial about the whole process

Comment: Thank you! Finally I created video file

Comment: Hi @Dim, have you tried to change duration/fps or images on video ?

Comment: @AbhishekV I updated to jcodec_0.1.7 as you suggested, but resultingly it removed a few methods like SequenceEncoder.encodeImage(bitmap,seconds); How to fix this?

Comment: @AbhishekV : In sample code, startDecode(View view) in FileChooserDialog statement giving error and does not import any class. I implemeted your way for setting up jcodec library.